# Battleship Game Field Generator

Tags: game, rust, battleship

**Summary**

I have been playing with Rust for a couple of days, so I thought I would implement something rather simple. This code generates a random variation of board for well-known game of [Battleship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_(game)). In this variation, there are one 4-cell ship, two 3-cell ships, three 2-cell ships and four 1-cell ships.

There's definitely a room for improvement both algorithm- and style-wise. Much appreciate the  help!

```
use itertools::Itertools;
use rand::rngs::SmallRng;
use rand::seq::SliceRandom;
use rand::{Rng, SeedableRng};

const FIELD_SIZE: isize = 10;
#[rustfmt::skip]
const DIRECTIONS: [(isize, isize); 9 as usize] = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1), (-1, 0), (1, 0), (-1, 1), (1, -1), (-1, -1), (1, 1)];

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Copy)]
enum CellType {
    EMPTY,
    UNAVAILABLE,
    OCCUPIED,
}

struct Field {
    field: [CellType; (FIELD_SIZE * FIELD_SIZE) as usize],
}

impl std::fmt::Display for Field {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        Ok(for (index, element) in self.field.iter().enumerate() {
            #[rustfmt::skip]
            let char_repr = match element {
                CellType::EMPTY       => '.',
                CellType::UNAVAILABLE => 'o',
                CellType::OCCUPIED    => 'X',
            };
            if index % FIELD_SIZE as usize == 0 {
                writeln!(f)?;
            }
            write!(f, "{}", char_repr)?;
        })
    }
}

fn is_valid_formation(
    field: &Field,
    mut x: isize,
    mut y: isize,
    dx: isize,
    dy: isize,
    ship_size: usize,
) -> bool {
    // I. Construct a bounding box for the placed ship.
    let bounds = 0..FIELD_SIZE;
    for ship_size in 0..ship_size {
        let x = x + (dx * ship_size as isize);
        let y = y + (dy * ship_size as isize);
        // Move in every box direction.
        for direction in DIRECTIONS.iter() {
            // Indices cannot be negative or >= FIELD_SIZE.
            if !bounds.contains(&(x + direction.0)) || !bounds.contains(&(y + direction.1)) {
                continue;
            }
            let bounding_box_cell =
                field.field[((x + direction.0) + ((y + direction.1) * FIELD_SIZE)) as usize];
            // If there's a ship within a bounding box, halt the loop -- we cannot place the ship here.
            if bounding_box_cell == CellType::OCCUPIED {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // II. Check whether the cells that are being used to place the ship onto are occupied.
    for _ in 0..ship_size {
        if !bounds.contains(&x) || !bounds.contains(&y) {
            return false;
        }
        let current_cell = field.field[(y * FIELD_SIZE + x) as usize];
        if let CellType::OCCUPIED | CellType::UNAVAILABLE = current_cell {
            return false;
        }
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
    }
    true
}

fn get_available_cells(
    field: &Field,
    dx: isize,
    dy: isize,
    ship_size: usize,
) -> Vec<(isize, isize)> {
    (0..FIELD_SIZE)
        .cartesian_product(0..FIELD_SIZE)
        .filter(|(x, y)| is_valid_formation(&field, *x, *y, dx, dy, ship_size))
        .collect()
}

fn emplace_ships(field: &mut Field, ship_size: usize, rng: &mut SmallRng) {
    // Flip a coin to determine an alignment (horizontal / vertical).
    let (dx, dy) = if rng.gen() { (1, 0) } else { (0, 1) };
    // Get the vector of appropriate cells.
    let cell_coordinates = get_available_cells(&field, dx, dy, ship_size);
    let (mut x, mut y) = cell_coordinates.choose(rng).unwrap();
    // Place a ship!
    for _ in 0..ship_size {
        field.field[(x + y * FIELD_SIZE) as usize] = CellType::OCCUPIED;
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
    }
}

impl Field {
    fn generate() -> Self {
        /* Generating the field. */
        let mut f = Field { field: [CellType::EMPTY; (FIELD_SIZE * FIELD_SIZE) as usize] };
        let mut rng: SmallRng = SmallRng::from_entropy();
        for ship_size in [4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1].iter() {
            emplace_ships(&mut f, *ship_size, &mut rng);
        }
        f
    }
}
fn main() {
    let field = Field::generate();
    println!("{}", field);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks good overall! For example, good job using `enum`s, and writing helpful comments. A few additional possible improvements, implemented below:

- In the declaration for `DIRECTIONS`, you don't need to cast `9` to `usize`; it can do so implicitly.
- Move the code for `char_repr` to an implementation of `Display` for `CellType`.
- Consider making more things `usize` instead of `isize`.
- A few minor things suggested by `clippy`, such as using `for x in &[...]` instead of `for x in [...].iter()`
- Comment what `index % FIELD_SIZE as usize == 0` does.
- Implement [`Index(Mut)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) for `Field`.
- Make things methods on `Field`.
- Rename `is_valid_formation` to `can_place_ship`.
- Create a `Ship` struct that implements [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) or [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html).
- Use `impl Rng` instead of `SmallRng` for code that doesn't care what kind of RNG is used.

Other things to consider, not implemented below:

- Unit tests
- Creating a `Coordinate` struct (may or may not be an improvement)

Final code:

```rust
#![warn(clippy::all)]
#![warn(clippy::pedantic)]
#![warn(clippy::nursery)]
#![allow(clippy::cast_possible_wrap)]
#![allow(clippy::cast_sign_loss)]

use itertools::Itertools;
use rand::rngs::SmallRng;
use rand::seq::SliceRandom;
use rand::{Rng, SeedableRng};
use std::fmt;
use std::ops::{Index, IndexMut};

const FIELD_SIZE: usize = 10;
#[rustfmt::skip]
const DIRECTIONS: [(isize, isize); 9] = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1), (-1, 0), (1, 0), (-1, 1), (1, -1), (-1, -1), (1, 1)];

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Copy)]
enum CellType {
    EMPTY,
    UNAVAILABLE,
    OCCUPIED,
}

impl fmt::Display for CellType {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(
            f,
            "{}",
            match self {
                Self::EMPTY => '.',
                Self::UNAVAILABLE => 'o',
                Self::OCCUPIED => 'X',
            }
        )
    }
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct ShipShape {
    dx: usize,
    dy: usize,
    size: usize,
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Ship {
    x: usize,
    y: usize,
    shape: ShipShape,
}

// If you prefer, you can use `IntoIterator` here instead.
#[allow(clippy::copy_iterator)]
impl Iterator for Ship {
    type Item = (usize, usize);

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<(usize, usize)> {
        if self.shape.size > 0 {
            let result = (self.x, self.y);
            self.x += self.shape.dx;
            self.y += self.shape.dy;
            self.shape.size -= 1;
            Some(result)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

struct Field {
    field: [CellType; (FIELD_SIZE * FIELD_SIZE) as usize],
}

impl fmt::Display for Field {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        for (index, element) in self.field.iter().enumerate() {
            // Start of line
            if index % FIELD_SIZE as usize == 0 {
                writeln!(f)?;
            }
            write!(f, "{}", element)?;
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}

impl Index<(usize, usize)> for Field {
    type Output = CellType;

    fn index(&self, (x, y): (usize, usize)) -> &CellType {
        &self.field[x + y * FIELD_SIZE]
    }
}

impl IndexMut<(usize, usize)> for Field {
    fn index_mut(&mut self, (x, y): (usize, usize)) -> &mut CellType {
        &mut self.field[x + y * FIELD_SIZE]
    }
}

impl Field {
    fn can_place_ship(&self, ship: Ship) -> bool {
        // I. Construct a bounding box for the placed ship.
        let bounds = 0..(FIELD_SIZE as isize);
        for (x, y) in ship {
            // Move in every box direction.
            for direction in &DIRECTIONS {
                // Indices cannot be negative or >= FIELD_SIZE.
                if !bounds.contains(&(x as isize + direction.0))
                    || !bounds.contains(&(y as isize + direction.1))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                let bounding_box_cell = self[(
                    (x as isize + direction.0) as usize,
                    (y as isize + direction.1) as usize,
                )];
                // If there's a ship within a bounding box, halt the loop -- we cannot place the ship here.
                if bounding_box_cell == CellType::OCCUPIED {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        // II. Check whether the cells that are being used to place the ship onto are occupied.
        let bounds = 0..FIELD_SIZE;
        for (x, y) in ship {
            if !bounds.contains(&x) || !bounds.contains(&y) {
                return false;
            }
            let current_cell = self[(x, y)];
            if let CellType::OCCUPIED | CellType::UNAVAILABLE = current_cell {
                return false;
            }
        }
        true
    }

    fn get_available_cells(&self, shape: ShipShape) -> Vec<(usize, usize)> {
        (0..FIELD_SIZE)
            .cartesian_product(0..FIELD_SIZE)
            .filter(|&(x, y)| self.can_place_ship(Ship { x, y, shape }))
            .collect()
    }

    fn emplace_ships(&mut self, size: usize, rng: &mut impl Rng) {
        // Flip a coin to determine an alignment (horizontal / vertical).
        let (dx, dy) = if rng.gen() { (1, 0) } else { (0, 1) };
        let shape = ShipShape { dx, dy, size };
        // Get the vector of appropriate cells.
        let cell_coordinates = self.get_available_cells(shape);
        let (x, y) = *cell_coordinates.choose(rng).unwrap();
        let ship = Ship { x, y, shape };
        // Place a ship!
        for (x, y) in ship {
            self[(x, y)] = CellType::OCCUPIED;
        }
    }

    fn generate() -> Self {
        /* Generating the field. */
        let mut result = Self {
            field: [CellType::EMPTY; FIELD_SIZE * FIELD_SIZE],
        };
        let mut rng: SmallRng = SmallRng::from_entropy();
        for ship_size in &[4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1] {
            result.emplace_ships(*ship_size, &mut rng);
        }
        result
    }
}
fn main() {
    let field = Field::generate();
    println!("{}", field);
}
```

<sup>Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=da8fca6fff5803ad9fe26957c3e70afa</sup>

Comment: Thanks! Besides; I think there is a way to get rid of unnecessary allocations by declaring an instance of StaticVec to pass into generating function. This significantly speeds things up.

Comment: Hello, on-line version works great, but in the final code I changed this line to get it running, from `use rand::rngs::StdRng;` to `use rand::rngs::StdRng as SmallRng;`. Cargo v1.49.0, rand="0.8.3", itertools="0.10.0".

Comment: @Malipivo You can also add the `small_rng` feature, see https://docs.rs/crate/rand/0.8.3/features and https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html. IIRC, you can use `rand = { version = "0.8.3", features = ["small_rng"] }`.